# Как получить свойство объекта?

Tags: php

Есть такой объект:

```
var_dump($category);

 object(SimpleXMLElement)[109]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '46' (length=2)
      'parentId' => string '3' (length=1)
  public 0 => string '3D' (length=2)
```

Как можно получить вот это свойство?:

```
 public 0 => string '3D' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще в XML нельзя имена начинать с цифры, соответственно они не могут состоять исключительно из цифры.

Но попробуйте такую конструкцию:

```
var_dump($category->{0});
```

или даже правильнее вот так

```
$x = 0;
var_dump($category->$x);
```

Comment: а так не изящнее сделать ? $categoryName = strval($category);

Comment: А разве можно применять strval() к объекту или массиву?

Comment: Это же не просто объект это SimpleXMLElement вот к примеру совет на мой вопрос https://toster.ru/q/359330 ?

Comment: Ну в том варианте и strval не нужен, проверьте в чем разница $categoryName = strval($category); echo $categoryName; с вариантом echo $category. Не могли бы вы показать как выглядит ваш XML?

Comment: тот который указан <category id='46' parent_id='3'>3D</category>

Comment: Ну тогда еще изящнее  $categoryName = $category->__toString();